# It is said that we all are descendants of Rishi Kashyap.How is it possible if there were total 7 distinct rishis?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, gotra

It is generally accepted that people who don't know their gotra can take Kashyap as their gotra. The reason being that kashap is the progenitor of all beings. Is it true?

Comment: Kashyapa is the foremost of all prajapatis. Both Devas & Asuras originate from him. There is an anecdote which states that when the earth was sinking down due to burden of sinners, Rishi Kashyapa held the earth on his right thigh (hence Bhudevi's name became Urvi, She who is held on the thigh). As the right thigh is reserved for daughters, the earth symbolically became Kashyapa's daughter & everything on earth, his descendant.